# Como fazer funçao PROCV (excel) em javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel

Como fazer a função Procv do excel no javascript;

Ex:

tenho uma tabela com 2 colunas (nome e codigo) e tenho uma lista apenas com nomes, 
preciso percorrer essa lista com nomes e trazer o codigo correspondente á cada nome de acordo com minha tabela citada acima .

Tabela

```
Nome    Codigo
João    340
Lucas   200
Tiago   120
```

Lista

```
['João','Lucas','Tiago']
```

Eu preciso trazer os codigos correspondentes á cada nome dessa lista .

---

Tenho um empasse na seguinte situação

tenho 2 json diferentes com 1 propriedade em comum. Neste caso ambos possuem numero em comum. preciso verificar se o numero do Json2 é igual ao do Json 1 , se forem iguais preciso exibir Numero e Nome do Json2 e Codigo do Json1.

```
  Json1 = [{"Codigo":1233123,"Numero":12345},
            {"Codigo":5345345,"Numero":45678},
            {"Codigo":34234,"Numero":8907},
            {"Codigo":423453,"Numero":340}]

  Json2 = [{"Numero":12345,"Nome":'Tiago'},
            {"Numero":45678,"Nome":'Joao'},
            {"Numero":8907,"Nome":'Paulo'},
            {"Numero":340,"Nome":'Maria'}]
```

Comment: Você procura uma função JS que faz o que o PROCV do excel faz, é isso?

Comment: Eu acho que você vai precisar fornecer mais detalhes. Edite a sua pergunta, exemplifique o seu problema *no JavaScript*. Do jeito que a sua pergunta está, só quem conhece Excel pode tentar inferir mais ou menos o que vc deseja. Foque no problema (se vc estiver processando uma tabela HTML, por exemplo, descreva isso!) e não na solução que vc já conhece no Excel.

Comment: sim Lucas Costa

Comment: Ok, melhorou. Tirei o meu voto pra fechar. Ainda assim, era bom vc deixar claro que tipo de tabela é essa. É um arquivo JSON? É uma tabela HTML? Caso contrário quem se interessa em te ajudar precisa *adivinhar* o que é. Facilite a sua vida facilitando a de quem vai te ajudar.

Comment: @LucasCosta    teria uma solução para á situação com Json ?

Comment: Ainda está com problema @ThallesHonorato? Pergunto porquê você até respondeu a sua pergunta com a solução.

Comment: @LucasCosta infelizmente errei em alguns aspectos na pergunta, ela esta reformulada se possivel analise , preciso fazer a comparação entre Json ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partindo do príncipio que essa é a estrutura da sua tabela, a idéia aqui é:

- Percorrer todas as células da tabela
- Visto que cada linha terá duas colunas, incrementar de dois em dois (e acessar o indice x e próximo para obter o nome o código
- Armazenar em um array de objetos o resultado

```js
var nomes = ['João', 'Lucas', 'Tiago'];

var itens = document.getElementById("corpo").querySelectorAll("td"); // obter cada célula da tabela

// obj sera o auxiliar para criar cada objeto, e procV é o array que conterá todos os objs
var obj = {},
  procV = [];

// iteracao de dois em dois, para percorrer linha por linha (nesse caso 3)
for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i = i + 2) {
  // reinicializa para um novo obj
  obj = {};
  obj.nome = nomes[nomes.indexOf(itens[i].innerHTML)];
  obj.valor = itens[i + 1].innerHTML;
  
  // adiciona no array de objeto
  procV.push(obj);
}

console.log(procV);
```

```html
<table id="proc" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Código</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="corpo">
    <tr>
      <td>Lucas</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiago</td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>João</td>
      <td>340</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o metodo acima pelo Lucas Costa consegui fazer esse "ProcV" utilizando uma fonte de dados em Json pra quem quiser de exemplo segue abaixo

```
var telefones = [64992072564, 64992573900, 64992824568, 64994077908, 32312323];

var data = { "teste":
              [{"Codigo":1233123,"Telefone":64992072564},
              {"Codigo":5345345,"Telefone":64992323232},
              {"Codigo":34234,"Telefone":64992573900},
              {"Codigo":423453,"Telefone":64992824568},
              {"Codigo":534,"Telefone":64993075236},
              {"Codigo":31231,"Telefone":64993325904},
              {"Codigo":5345345,"Telefone":64993576572},
              {"Codigo":312312,"Telefone":64993827240},
              {"Codigo":5345,"Telefone":64994077908},
              {"Codigo":3123,"Telefone":64994328576},
              {"Codigo":4353453,"Telefone":64994579244},
              {"Codigo":31231,"Telefone":64994829912},
              {"Codigo":645645,"Telefone":64995080580},
              {"Codigo":4234234,"Telefone":64995331248},
              {"Codigo":64564,"Telefone":64995581916},
              {"Codigo":42342,"Telefone":64995832584},
              {"Codigo":6456456,"Telefone":64996083252}]
};

var objeto = {},
    procV = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.teste.length; i++) {

    var teste = data.teste[i];
    obj = {};
    obj.telefone = telefones[telefones.indexOf(teste.Telefone)];

    // Se houver telefones da lista telefones no meu json ele procura o codigo e faz o push 
    if(obj.telefone > 0){
         obj.codigo = teste.Codigo;
         procV.push(obj);
    }

}

console.log(procV);
```

Comment: Se a resposta do colega Lucas te ajudou, vote nela e marque-a como aceita. Não poste como você a utilizou. Novamente, este site não é um fórum. Convém dar uma lidinha na [help] pra entender melhor como ele funciona, ok? :) Vai te ajudar no futuro.